# How to show that in a system of two dimensionless differential equations, the difference between their state variables converges to zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking at systems of (nonlinear) differential equations in the spirit of Strogatz' *Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos*.

> Given a system of
>
> - $\frac{dx}{dt} = y^3 - 4x$
> - $\frac{dy}{dt} = y^3 - y- 3x$
>
> show that $|x(t) - y(t)| \rightarrow 0$ for $t \rightarrow \infty$.

My basic idea was to consider (very informally) 
$$|x(t) - y(t)| = |x(t-1) + \frac{dx}{dt} - y(t-1) + \frac{dy}{dt}| \\= |x(t-1) - y(t-1) - x + y | "=" 0$$
i.e. looking at the change from one timepoint to another and then seeing that the whole thing cancels itself out.

However, I don't really know how to express this idea properly. Further, as of yet I am not considering "low" values of $t$ or using that $t \rightarrow \infty$.

I'd be grateful for any tips on how to go about this.

Comment: Tip: consider the variable $z=x-y$. Can you write ODE for $z$?

Comment: Substract both equations then  $|x-y|=Ke^{-t}$

Answer (score 1):

If you substract both equations, you get:
$$x'-y'=y-x$$
$$\int \frac {d(x-y)}{x-y}=-\int dt$$
$$\int \frac {d(x-y)}{x-y}=-t+c$$
$$\implies \ln |x-y|=-t+c$$
$$|x-y|=Ke^{-t}$$
Then you have:
$$|x-y|\rightarrow 0 \text { for } t \rightarrow \infty$$